# $k[x]$-module is $k$-vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

> Could anyone tell me why an $A$-module is a $k$-vector space with a linear transformation? (Here $A=k[x]$ where $k$ is a field.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is a structure of a module over $k[x]$ on a vector space $V$? It is by definition a map  of algebras $k[x]\to End(V)$. How do you describe such maps? Can you see where $1\in k[x]$ must go? Where $x$ can go? If you know this data, do you know where any monomial $x^r$ must go?

Comment: I think 1 must go to the identity map. Is it by definition 1x=x for any x in M?

Comment: And x can go anywhere?

Comment: Exactly! $x$ can go to any matrix. If you know where $x$ goes, say, to matrix $A$, can you tell where $x^2$ should then go? What about $x^3$?

Comment: I think $x^2$ should go to $A^2$, $x^3$ should go to $A^3$.

Comment: Then what does it mean by linear transformation? Is it refer to the matrix corresponding to x?

Comment: Any matrix defines a linear transformation. And backwards, if you have a linear transformation, if you fix a basis in your vector space, it will give you a matrix, matrix of this linear transformation. So linear transformations are like matrices, but by default without given basis.

Comment: Thanks! If given a basis then we can get a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Let's unwrap the definitions. An $A$-module $M$ is an abelian group with an action of $A$ satisfying certain axioms. Since $k$ is a subring of $A$, $k$ also acts on $M$, that is, $M$ is a $k$-vector space. The rest of the action is determined by that of $x$ and the module axioms, and since $x$ doesn't satisfy any relations in $A$, we can let $x$ act as any $k$-linear endomorphism of $M$.

Comment: Thanks! I see that M is a k vector space.

Comment: Why x act as a k-linear endomorphism? I don't quite understand "linear" here. Is that mean x($k_1$+$k_2$)=a$k_1$+b$k_2$ for any $k_1$ and $k_2$, and some a and b?

Comment: I mean $x(a_1m_1+a_2m_2)=a_1xm_1+a_2xm_2$ for $m_1,m_2\in M$ and $a_1,a_2\in k$. This is required by the module axioms and the fact that $A$ has commutative multiplication.

Comment: I think I get it. I guess k acts canonically and x can be any transformation which satisfies the condition you just mentioned. That's why it is a k vector space with a linear transformation, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!